# Auto Incrementing Primary Key Using Entry Widgets into Table

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using entries to insert data points into a table where the 'ID' is auto-incrementing. I'm encountering an issue I had when I was working on importing a table with the id being based on auto incrementing, but the solutions I got for that haven't worked with this so far.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl (
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     data text
     )""")

def add_equipment():
     conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
     c = conn.cursor()
     c.execute("INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(:ID + null, :data)
          {"data":data_ent.get()
          })
     conn.commit()
     conn.close()
```

Doing this gives me an error of did not supply value for binding parameter id, removing the ':id + null' gives me an error of 1 column doens't have a supplied value. I used a for loop on the import version of this, but when I tried to do a loop as:

```
     for row in c.fetchall():
          c.execute('variable for the insert command & data', row)
```

it gives me no error, but doesn't insert the data into the table. I assume the for loop is wrong, but I'm not sure what it should be since this is meant to insert a single record at a time.

Comment: What is `data_ent.get()` in `add_equipment()`? What is `c` of `c.fetchall()` in the `for` loop?

Comment: @forpas data_ent.get() is a shortened version of the rest of the table insert since there's 270 points. I'm using .get() on entry widgets to get the information to insert into the table. c.fetchall() is the best guess I have as to how to incorporate a for loop similar to what you taught me on the import, except I don't really know how to do a for loop for this case.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def add_equipment():
     conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
     c = conn.cursor()
     c.execute("INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(:ID + null, :data)
          {"id":'NULL',
           "data":data_ent.get()
          })
     conn.commit()
     conn.close()
```

This gives id a binding parameter and allows the null to auto increment as supposed to.